# Call google-map Function in main python program and pass arguments in python

Tags: python, function, google-maps-api-3

I need to defined a function that include two parameters. The arguments are supplied in main python program which calls the function in it. The function calls googlemapsapi to calculate travel time. The main program can call the function, but not taking arguments supplied. Function executed without the supplied arguments.

## function:

```
def travel_time(origin,destination):
return value

print("Below is Drive Time");
now = datetime.now()

directions_result_drive = gmaps.directions(origin,
                                 destination,
                                   mode="driving",                                     
                                 departure_time=now
                                )
value=round(float((directions_result_drive[0]['legs'][0]['duration']
```

['value'])/3600),1)

## Main program is as below:

```
from travel_function import travel_time
origin = input("origin is:",)
destination = input("destination is:",)
print(travel_time(origin,destination));
```

Based on argument supplied, it should give travel time. e.g. Origin=NewYork, Destination="Boston", value returned should be approx. 4 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only problem is that the return statement is at the top, this should work:

```
def travel_time(origin, destination):

    print("Below is Drive Time")
    now = datetime.now()

    directions_result_drive = gmaps.directions(
        origin,
        destination,
        mode="driving",                                     
        departure_time=now
    )
    value = round(float((directions_result_drive[0]['legs'][0]['duration']['value'])/3600),1)
    return value
```